# Checkbox Always Returns False MVC5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I am using checkboxes and radio buttons in my forms, I can get all the values except the checkboxes, it always returns False.

My Model Code

```
public bool Gender { get; set; }  //checkbox

        public bool MStatus { get; set; }  //radio button
 public void Astudent(Student stu)
    {
        try
        {
            NpgsqlConnection con = new NpgsqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["npg"].ConnectionString);
            string stat = "";
            if(stu.MStatus==true)
            {
                stat = "M";
            }
            else
            {
                stat = "S";
            }
            string gnd = "";
            if (stu.Gender == true)
            {
                gnd = "M";
            }
            else
            {
                gnd = "F";
            }
            StringBuilder qry = new StringBuilder();
            qry.Append("select * from fldata(");
            qry.Append("(ARRAY[");
            qry.Append("'(");
            qry.Append(stu.Id);
            qry.Append(",");
            qry.Append(stu.FName);
            qry.Append(",");
            qry.Append(stu.LName);
            qry.Append(",");
            qry.Append(stu.UName);
            qry.Append(",");
            qry.Append(stu.Email);
            qry.Append(",");
            qry.Append(gnd);
            qry.Append(",");
            qry.Append(stat);
            qry.Append(",");
            qry.Append(stu.Department);
            qry.Append(")'])::ful[]");
            qry.Append(")");
            con.Open();
            NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand(qry.ToString(), con);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
             ex.ToString();
        }

    }
```

My Controller Code

```
  public ActionResult Complex() // Add New EE / Student
    {


        return View();
    }


    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Complex(Student stu) // Add New EE / Student
    {
        Student empadd = new Student();
        empadd.Astudent(stu);
        return RedirectToAction("ComplexView");

    }
```

My View Code

```
    @model postgre.Models.Student
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Complex";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>AddEmployee</h2>



<section class="panel-body">
    @Html.ValidationSummary()
</section>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{

    <p>
        First Name:
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.FName, new { @class = "form-control" })
    </p>
    <p>
        Last Name:
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.LName, new { @class = "form-control" })
    </p>
    <p>
        User Name:
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.UName, new { @class = "form-control" })
    </p>
    <p>
        Email:
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Email, new { @class = "form-control" })
    </p>
    <p>
        Gender:<br /> 
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(Model => Model.Gender, new { @class = "form-check-input", @name = "gender", @value = "M", @checked = true }) &nbsp;Male&nbsp;
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(Model => Model.Gender, new { @class = "form-check-input", @name = "gender", @value = "F",})&nbsp;Female&nbsp;
    </p>
    <p>
        Marital Status:<br />   
        @Html.RadioButtonFor(Model => Model.MStatus, new { @class = "form-check-input", @name = "mstat", @value = "S" })&nbsp;Single&nbsp;
        @Html.RadioButtonFor(Model => Model.MStatus, new { @class = "form-check-input", @name = "mstat", @value = "M", @select = true })&nbsp;Married&nbsp;
    </p>
    <p>
        @Html.DropDownListFor(Model => Model.Department,
                      new SelectListItem[]{
                      new SelectListItem() {Text = "Select Your Department", Value=""},
                      new SelectListItem() {Text = "IT", Value="IT"},
                      new SelectListItem() {Text = "Management", Value="Management"},
                      new SelectListItem() {Text = "Commerce", Value="Commerce"}}, new {@class="form-control" })
    </p>
    <p><input type="submit" name="add" value="Add Employee" class="btn btn-primary" /></p>

}
```

I tried many ways like using `@checked="checked"` or `@Checked=true` , but its not working, when ever I submit my forms it returns the False.
As I am new to MVC and Razor, so not able to get it.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: A checkbox binds to a `bool` and a `public bool Gender` property makes no sense. And never attempt to set the `name` attribute or the `value` attribute when using the `HtmlHelper` methods - fortunately your `@name=".."` does absolutely nothing, and setting the `value` to `"M"` means it cannot bind (a `bool` can only have one of 2 values - `true` or `false`)

Comment: Change the property to `string Gender` (or use an `enum`) and use radio buttons.

Comment: Thanks @StephenMuecke

Comment: Forgive the off-topic comment, but the way you build your SQL string is atrocious. It opens you right up for a SQL Injection attack.

Answer (score -2):

I have just updated the View Checkbox and Radio Button code, now its working fine.

For peoples who have same issue, please review the code, hope it will help them.

```
 <p>
    Gender:<br /> 
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(Model => Model.Gender, new { @class = "form-check-input"}) &nbsp;Male&nbsp;
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(Model => Model.Gender, new { @class = "form-check-input"})&nbsp;Female&nbsp;
</p>
<p>
    Marital Status:<br />   
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(Model => Model.MStatus,true, new { @class = "form-check-input"})&nbsp;Single&nbsp;
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(Model => Model.MStatus,false, new { @class = "form-check-input" })&nbsp;Married&nbsp;
</p>
```

Comment: You answer makes no sense at all (and it certainly not helpful to anyone). You have 2 checkboxes for `Gender` and only the first one will ever be bound so the 2nd one is pointless. And since they are checkboxes, a use can select both or select none which makes even less sense. And how in the world can `Gender` have a value of `true` or `false` (what is `Gender=true` supposed to mean)

Comment: And your radio buttons for `MStatus` also make no sense. Again what is `MStatus=true` supposed to mean - You are saying that if you are single then your marital status is `true` and if you are married then your marital status is `false`

Comment: @StephenMuecke Sir, I think you have less knowledge about the codding, or you don't know about the logic.
So I don't need to explain things here. :P :*